# TTGO lora32 Guru Meditation Error: Core 1 panic'ed (Interrupt wdt timeout on CPU1)

Tags: serial-port, arduino-esp32

I'm having problems with the ttglo lora32 oled, I programmed it in Arduino IDE. The code basically does the following; It obtains the temperature and humidity data from a DHT22, displays them on the integrated OLED screen, then, using the JSON library, creates a string with json format and finally sends the string with a serial.Print through the serial port.

Everything works correctly for a few minutes (approximately 15) and then the microcontroller sends the following error through the serial port:

```
Guru Meditation Error: Core  1 panic'ed (Interrupt wdt timeout on CPU1). 

Core  1 register dump:
PC      : 0x400d335c  PS      : 0x00060e35  A0      : 0x800d3434  A1      : 0x3ffb20b0  
A2      : 0x0001f7e4  A3      : 0x00000001  A4      : 0x3ffc1cec  A5      : 0x00000001  
A6      : 0x00ff0000  A7      : 0xff000000  A8      : 0x00027100  A9      : 0x0001f7e4  
A10     : 0x00000001  A11     : 0x00000000  A12     : 0x7f170ed5  A13     : 0x00002000  
A14     : 0x00000028  A15     : 0xff000000  SAR     : 0x0000000d  EXCCAUSE: 0x00000006  
EXCVADDR: 0x00000000  LBEG    : 0x400845e5  LEND    : 0x400845ed  LCOUNT  : 0x00000027  


Backtrace: 0x400d3359:0x3ffb20b0 0x400d3431:0x3ffb20d0 0x400d3609:0x3ffb2230 0x400d1658:0x3ffb2250 0x400d2111:0x3ffb2270 0x400d5b71:0x3ffb2290
```

The code is the following:

```
#include <Wire.h>
#include <Adafruit_GFX.h>
#include <Adafruit_SSD1306.h>
#include "DHT.h"
#include <ArduinoJson.h>

#define DHTPIN 13

String resultS = "";
int var = 0;
int num = 1;
boolean db = false;
#define DHTTYPE DHT22 
DHT dht(DHTPIN, DHTTYPE);

Adafruit_SSD1306 myDisplay = Adafruit_SSD1306(128,64,&Wire);

int t = 0;
int h = 0;
float tp,hp;

void setup() 
{  
  Serial.begin(9600);
  dht.begin();
  myDisplay.begin(SSD1306_SWITCHCAPVCC, 0x3C);  
  num = 1;
}

void loop() 
{
  
  db = false;
  for(int i = 1; i <= 900; i++) //tiempo en segundos para cada muestra en la base de datos
  { 
    lectura();
    display();
    myDisplay.display();
    delay(1000); 
    json();
  }  
  db = true;
  lectura();
  display();
  myDisplay.display();
  delay(1000);
  json();
  num++;   
}

void lectura ()
{
  hp = dht.readHumidity() * 0.9598 - 4.6208 + 1; 
  tp = dht.readTemperature() * 0.8779 + 1.9411 -1;
  t = ((int)(tp * 10));
  h = ((int)(hp * 10));
}

void display()
{
  myDisplay.clearDisplay();
  myDisplay.setTextColor(WHITE);
  
  myDisplay.setTextSize(2);
  myDisplay.setCursor(0,0);
  myDisplay.print("Temp: ");
  myDisplay.setTextSize(2);
  myDisplay.setCursor(43,16);
  myDisplay.print(tp);
  myDisplay.print(" C");

  myDisplay.setTextSize(2);
  myDisplay.setCursor(0,34);
  myDisplay.print("Hum: ");
  myDisplay.setTextSize(2);
  myDisplay.setCursor(43,50);
  myDisplay.print(hp);
  myDisplay.print(" %");
}
void json ()
{
  StaticJsonDocument<96> doc;
  
    doc["N"] = num;
    doc["Dispositivo"] = "dosificado_2_ss"; 
    doc["Temperatura"] = t;
    doc["humedad"] = h;
    doc["db"] = db;
  
    String output;    
    serializeJson(doc, output);  
    Serial.println(output);   
}
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: If you change the  `StaticJsonDocument<96> doc;` to `StaticJsonDocument<128> doc;`, will it work?

Comment: i tried it, but i'm having the same issue.

Comment: If your code running for several minutes and crash, it is likely your code somehow crashes due to running out of memory due to memory leak or heap fragmentation. 1) Download and install [EPS Exception Decoder](https://github.com/me-no-dev/EspExceptionDecoder) to decode the exception code to see where it caused the crash. 2) add `ESP.getFreeHeap()` at end of the `loop()` to see if the value remain relatively constant?